# How can I deactivate several buttons when I click a button?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am having a button pattern in my python and qt  UI. The pattern is 3x3 which means 9 buttons in total.
Every button has a specific function. Now I am looking for a way to disable the other 8 buttons while 1 button is checked and re activate the other 8 buttons when the button is unchecked.

I tried to create a list of buttons to iterate through it when I click a button but I failed getting it to work since my buttons in the list becoming a string.

```
class Startscreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Startscreen,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Main.ui",self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.funct1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.funct2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.funct3)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.funct4)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.funct5)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.funct6)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.funct7)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.funct8)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.funct9)

    def funct1(self,checked):
        if checked: 
            self.dosomething(1)
        elif not checked: 
            print("i am not checked")
```

there are 8 other def functions. So I need help to find a way how to disable the other 8 buttons when 1 function is called.
I dont wanna copy paste `self.pushButton_2-9.setEnabled(False)` every time.
Is there some more elegant way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the buttons to a button group and use its signals instead

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QButtonGroup
```

Assuming all your buttons are checkable, create a button group object and add each of the buttons into it

```
# ASSUMING ALL THE BUTTONS ARE CHECKABLE
self.button_group = QButtonGroup(self)
self.button_group.setExclusive(False)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_2)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_3)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_4)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_5)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_6)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_7)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_8)
self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_9)
```

Then create a slot to handle button toggled events

```
@pyqtSlot(QAbstractButton, bool)
def button_toggled(self, button: QAbstractButton, checked: bool):
  for btn in self.button_group.buttons():
    if not btn is button:
      btn.setDisabled(checked)
```

Then connect the **buttonToggled** signal of the button_group to the the created slot

```
def connect_signals(self):
  self.button_group.buttonToggled.connect(self.button_toggled)
```

Your complete code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QButtonGroup # ... your other imports

class Startscreen(QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Startscreen,self).__init__()
    loadUi("Main.ui",self)
    # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.funct1)
    # self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.funct2)
    # self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.funct3)
    # self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.funct4)
    # self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.funct5)
    # self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.funct6)
    # self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.funct7)
    # self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.funct8)
    # self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.funct9)

    # ASSUMING ALL THE BUTTONS ARE CHECKABLE
    self.button_group = QButtonGroup(self)
    self.button_group.setExclusive(False)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_2)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_3)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_4)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_5)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_6)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_7)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_8)
    self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_9)

    self.connect_signals()

  def connect_signals(self):
    self.button_group.buttonToggled.connect(self.button_toggled)

  @pyqtSlot(QAbstractButton, bool)
  def button_toggled(self, button: QAbstractButton, checked: bool):
    for btn in self.button_group.buttons():
      if not btn is button:
        btn.setDisabled(checked)

  # def funct1(self,checked):
  #   if checked: 
  #     self.dosomething(1)
  #   elif not checked: 
  #     print("i am not checked")
```

Aside:

You could also assign buttonGroup to buttons directly in the designer.

Select the button(s) you want to group together, then right click and select **Assign to button group** option, then select a button group, or create a newButtonGroup which you can rename to whatever name.

Then on the buttongroup properties editor, uncheck the exclusive checkbox.
Save to a **.ui** file, then convert it to a **.py** file

To convert the **.ui** file to **.py** file, first, locate the **pyuic6.exe** file on your machine, get its complete path then on cmd execute this

```
C:/path/to/pyuic6.exe -x "C:/path/to/window.ui" -o "C:/path/to/ui_window.py"
```

On windows run this on cmd and it should show you the complete path to the pyuic6.exe file

```
where pyuic6
```

Assuming your project structure is like this:

```
proj_folder
  window.ui
  ui_window.py
  main.py
```

your **main.py** file should resemble something like this:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QAbstractButton
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import ui_window
import sys, os


class Startscreen(QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Startscreen, self).__init__()

    # initialize the ui
    self.ui = ui_window.Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # access the componets, e.g buttons like this
    # self.ui.pushButton
    # self.ui.pushButton_2
    # this way, if you are using IDE like PyCharm or VsCode, hinting is available
    # then everything is just like before, create a slot to handle the toggle events and 
    # connect to the signal

    self.connect_signals()

  def connect_signals(self):
    self.ui.button_group.buttonToggled.connect(self.button_clicked)

  # create slot to handle the buttons toggle events, just like before
  @pyqtSlot(QAbstractButton, bool)
  def button_clicked(self, button: QAbstractButton, checked: bool):
    for btn in self.ui.button_group.buttons(): # NOTICE self.ui.
      if not btn is button:
        btn.setDisabled(checked)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.system('cls')
  try:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Startscreen()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
  finally:
    print('[INFO] [App is closing...]')
```

This is the **window.ui** that I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>131</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="central_widget" native="true">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 1</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 2</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 3</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 4</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 5</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 6</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 7</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 8</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Button 9</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checkable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="buttonGroup">
         <string notr="true">button_group</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <buttongroups>
  <buttongroup name="button_group">
   <property name="exclusive">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </buttongroup>
 </buttongroups>
</ui>
```

and the resultant **ui_window.py**. NOTE: You should never edit this code otherwise any changes made will be lost once you reconvert the .ui file to the same .py file

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'window.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.3.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(300, 131)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.button_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Dialog)
        self.button_group.setObjectName("button_group")
        self.button_group.setExclusive(False)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_5.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_4.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_6.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_6)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_8.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_8)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_7.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_7)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.pushButton_9.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.button_group.addButton(self.pushButton_9)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 3"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 4"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 5"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 6"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 7"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 8"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button 9"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This was tested on Windows 10 pro, Python version 3.9.10, PyQt6 version 6.3.0

I hope it helps, PEACE!